# How to get all the shared folders in Windows XP using Java

Tags: java, windows-xp

How can i get all the shared folders in Windows XP in my local system using java.

Thanks

Comment: folders shared on your local machine or on a remote system? First would require looking at the local setup, second would require a query on the connected box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to query in my local system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net share
```

Try executing this command in windows machine.
[Here is sample how to execute commands from java code](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-execute-a-command-from-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        String line = null;
        String[] commands = new String[] { "cmd", "/C", "net share" };
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        InputStream ins = child.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while (!(line = buffReader.readLine()).trim().equals(
                "The command completed successfully.")) {
            System.out.println(line);
             }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
```