# Using a JFileChooser to choose net shares

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need to enable users in my application to save a file into a shared folder. I suppose I could let them type the path and then check if it is really valid, but I´d prefer something more user-friendly. Is there a way to coax a JFileChooser into displaying only network clients and their shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java as a platform neutral language doesn't allow you to access Windows specific services, so there is no way to do that.

But you can use a library like JCIFS (see this question: [Get all shared directories on a remote Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210977/get-all-shared-directories-on-a-remote-server)) and build your own dialog which looks like `JFileChooser`.

Comment: Didn´t think about portability. Thanks.